# APS (Forge) Viewer section tool throws errors while rotating a cut plane

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Recently I'm getting errors consecutively as soon as I try to rotate a cut plane in an Autodesk Forge Viewer:

[image]

And I need to reload the page to stop throwing these errors.

I'm using the latest viewer script:
"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js".

In the browser console, the errors are as follows:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.
    at W.uploadTexture (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1359312)
    at W.setTexture (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1359506)
    at https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1346262
    at Nt (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1346627)
    at W.renderBufferDirect (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1322647)
    at _t (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1321202)
    at bt (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1320734)
    at xt (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1321099)
    at W.render (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:1332213)
    at W.render (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js:18:431135)
```